# How to use php to get each matched regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting to use preg_match_all to extract a repeated pattern out of an html string.

The problem seems to be that my pattern has a defined beginning and end, but a wildcard portion in between. So the `preg_match_all` ends up only getting the biggest match, but not the individual matches.

My ultimate goal is to isolate each `<a ...>some text</a>` out of an html string, and to wrap them as so: `<font ...><a ...>some text</a></font>`.

But first off I want to simply successfully isolate them each:

```
$lvs_regex = "/<a.+<\/a>/" ;
$lvs_test  = "click <a href='...'>AAA</a> now, <a href='...'>BBB</a> later, <a href='...'>CCC</a> tomorrow" ;

preg_match_all( $lvs_regex , $lvs_test , $matches ) ;
for($i = 0 ; $i < count( $matches ) ; $i++ )
  { print $matches[ $i ][0] . "<br/>" ;
  }
```

The return that I want:

[0] => `<a href='...'>AAA</a>`

[1] => `<a href='...'>BBB</a>`

[2] => `<a href='...'>CCC</a>`

But I only get one match:

[0] => `<a href='...'>AAA</a> now, <a href='...'>BBB</a> later, <a href='...'>CCC</a>`

Comment: Read up on [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) with `.*?` or use a negated character class to only match non-tagish content in between.

Comment: Instead of enclose each links inside `<font>` tags, why you don't use a css rule?

Comment: Casimir, the text is actually being sent to flash, which has limits on its html text.

Comment: Mario ... 'greediness' was a concept that I had never heard of .. it got me on the right track, and enabled me to understand ilpaijin's answer.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd: I can't wait that this technology disappears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$lvs_regex = "/<a.*?<\/a>/" ;
$lvs_test  = "click <a href='...'>AAA</a> now, <a href='...'>BBB</a> later, <a href='...'>CCC</a> tomorrow" ;

preg_match_all( $lvs_regex , $lvs_test , $matches);
```

Basically the pattern needed is `/<a.*?<\/a>/`. This match every occurrence in your string.

Now, `var_dump($matches[0])` gives

```
array (size=3)
    0 => string '<a href='...'>AAA</a>' (length=21)
    1 => string '<a href='...'>BBB</a>' (length=21)
    2 => string '<a href='...'>CCC</a>' (length=21)
```

that is the return that you want.

So by following with

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < count( $matches[0] ) ; $i++ )
{ 
    var_dump($matches[0][ $i ] . "<br/>");
}
```

you see now it's matching every occurrence:

```
string '<a href='...'>AAA</a><br/>' (length=26)
string '<a href='...'>BBB</a><br/>' (length=26)
string '<a href='...'>CCC</a><br/>' (length=26)
```

-------- NEW EDIT ---------

So now you can modifiy your loop in order to wrap every `a` tag matched.

```
$result='';

for($i = 0 ; $i < count( $matches[0] ) ; $i++ )
{ 
    $result .= "<font ...>".$matches[0][ $i ] . "</font><br/>";
} 

var_dump($result);
```

And you get

`<font ...><a href='...'>AAA</a></font><br/><font ...><a href='...'>BBB</a></font><br/><font ...><a href='...'>CCC</a></font><br/>`

---------- NEW EDIT ----------

As suggested @Casimir et Hippolyte by you can avoid the matching of "wrong or unwanted" tag as `abbr` by adding a word boudary in the pattern:

```
$lvs_regex = "/<a\b.*?<\/a>/" ;
```

and optionally obtain the same result by using a foreach instead of a for loop. Ex:

```
foreach($matches[0] as $matches)
{ 
    $result .= "<font ...>".$matches . "</font><br/>";
}
```

And a [link](http://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html) about `foreach` internal behaviour, in case you would get a deep look at the construct.

Comment: that works ... I incorrectly posted that it did not work because I did not notice the `$matches[0]...` part of your answer ... sorry, and thanks.

Comment: Adding a word boundary avoid to match an <abbr> tag: `<a\b...`. Why using a for loop when foreach can do the job?

Comment: You're absolutely right but I tent to not entirely explode the OP code, trying to follow his direction. I think it's part of his journey to find the correct way to do his stuff. By the way I'll edit the code with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
$lvs_regex = "/<a.+<\/a>/U" ;

$lvs_test  = "click <a href='...'>AAA</a> now, <a href='...'>BBB</a> later, <a href='...'>CCC</a> tomorrow" ;

preg_match_all( $lvs_regex , $lvs_test , $matches ) ;
if ($matches) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        print $match."\n";
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
<a href='...'>AAA</a>
<a href='...'>BBB</a>
<a href='...'>CCC</a>
```

Use 'ungreedy' specificator /U

http://www.php.net/manual/fa/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php